# Error in Faraway "Linear Models with R" treatment of confidence intervals?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, linear-model, ellipse

I have recently been reading Faraway ["Linear Models with R"](https://www.routledge.com/Linear-Models-with-R/Faraway/p/book/9781439887332) and I am particularly interested in the section for computing and plotting confidence intervals. On page 45, he provides the following plot:

[image]

From the following data:

```
require(faraway)
lmod <- lm(Species ~ Area + Elevation + Nearest + Scruz + Adjacent, gala)
```

How was the point `A` calculated? Because when I calculate for the confidence interval

```
> confint(lmod).   2.5%.     97.5%
(Intercept)     -32.464101 46.600542
Area            -0.070216  0.022339 
Elevation        0.208710  0.430219
Nearest         -2.166486  2.184774 
Scruz           -0.685093  0.204044
Adjacent        -0.111336 -0.038273
```

Shouldn't A represent

```
x = -0.070216, y= -0.111336
```

Suggesting it's plotted at the lower left within the circle?

So that this is not purely a code-based question- How do I infer the confidence intervals from an ellipse plot?

Comment: Which edition of the book is it? [2nd](https://www.routledge.com/Linear-Models-with-R/Faraway/p/book/9781439887332)?

Comment: @RichardHardy This is the second edition, however it may just be my lack of understanding hypotheses with ellipses. I believe the left corner of the rectangle is the 2.5% confidence interval and the upper right corner is the 97.5th confidence interval. However, I cannot understand what `A` and `B` represent here or how these were calculated, if they are not these confidence intervals?

Comment: You appear to be thinking of confidence regions as rectangles.  But the rectangle defined by the Cartesian product of $1-\alpha$ confidence intervals would be a $(1-\alpha)^2$ region if the variable estimates were independent; and the variable estimates are not independent. Doesn't the book explain how to obtain simultaneous confidence regions? If not, then please check out [some of our explanations](https://stats.stackexchange.com/search?q=confidence+ellipse).